# Zend: undefined variable in php page

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I have an error.php file which can be grossly simplified to:

```
<?

  if (!isset($error))
    $error = "Unspecified Error";

  echo "Error: $error";

?>
```

It is not "normal usage" to just navigate to error.php. Rather, I would do something like:

```
$dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

if (!$dbh)
{
  $error = "Can't connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
  include('error.php');
  exit();
}
```

That said, if the user *does* navigate to error.php then they will just get "Error: Unspecified Error" as expected.

All my code is working, and the error page shows up and works exactly as expected, however Zend is complaining that $error is undefined on the line: `if (!isset($error))`.

I realise my design pattern is awful, but I'm just throwing together something quick-and-dirty in this case.

Comment: It is undefined, but isn't that what `isset()` is for really?

Comment: @alex Well, yes... I suppose so. I wasn't asking because my code isn't working; I was asking because Zend is giving me warnings. At the moment I'm just ignoring them since they're not really a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better idea, create a function instead:

```
function output_error( $error = NULL )
{
    if( !$error ) $error = "Unspecified Error";
    echo "Error: $error";
}
```

It has the benefit of both removing the Zend issue, and you have a *MUCH* better design. Then:

```
if (!$dbh)
{
  include('error.php');
  output_error( "Can't connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error() );
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Even if my _actual_ error.php (not the simplified one I put in as an example) outputs a full html error page with head, stylesheets, and javascript?

Comment: +1, by the way. I think this is the only proper answer so far.

Comment: At the of the page `<?php function output_errors($err){?>` at the bottom `<?php }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

if (!$dbh){
  $error = "Can't connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
  if（!include('error.php'){
      echo $error;
      exit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:
`if (!isset(@$error))`.